# web3.js version is 1.2.1 , Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?

Tags: solidity

my web3.js version is 1.2.1

```
let testAddr = "0x0c1A5F4556B09C89D29c1F4C4b2497EEd81aF31D";
    let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress, {gasPrice: '3000000', from: userAddr});
    web3.eth.getBalance(userAddr).then(console.log)
    // let options = {
 //            from: userAddr, //创建账户用主账号
 //            gas: 8000000, //最大的gas数值
 //            gasPrice:"2100000" 
 //        }
    contract.methods.findUser(userAddr).call().then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

> Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?
>       at ABICoder.decodeParameters (/home/zhr/solspace/house_rent/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js:226:15)
>       at Contract._decodeMethodReturn (/home/zhr/solspace/house_rent/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:465:22)
>       at Method.outputFormatter (/home/zhr/solspace/house_rent/node_modules/

Comment: What is `testAddr` here for???

Comment: Without a reproducible example is hard to know what is wrong or where it is failing (ie contract code, javascript code). My guess is that findUser is failing, it is expecting some output but the output is empty. And it fails because contract was not initialized properly.

Comment: Find the contract whether have testAddr, which already register in the contract